# How to return to an html page without reloading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My application has a page that allows the user to select one of a number of reports, supply some  report parameters, and then click a button to generate the report.

The report is displayed in a new browser page (or tab as the case may be).  If the user clicks back onto the initial report selection page, it is reloaded, thus losing whatever report parameters the user selected.

Is there a way to prevent the report selection page from reloading under these circumstances?

Comment: There are several ways to preserve data. With a full page refresh, only using JavaScript, you could try local storage.

Comment: Yes, that's my fallback method but wanted to check if there was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript you could use localStorage to preserve the parameters between page refreshes. Like this, to save the state:

```
localStorage.setItem('myReportParameter1', 'myValue1');
```

and then retrieve the value when the page is loaded again:

```
var param1 = localStorage.getItem("myReportParameter1");
```

another option is to push the parameters to the URL, and in that case it can be copy pasted, but if its a lot of params or complex objects youre better off with localstorage.

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought of using $_SESSION to store the parameters since there's a php script that runs when the page is loaded but hadn't thought of doing the same thing via js.

Comment: well, you never mentioned PHP, only JS =) Were not familiar with your environment. Session could just as well store your state, and when the page is rendered (if served via php) the previos values could be outputted directly in the html